# Highchart multiple threshold colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm taking a look at this Highcharts fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/YWVHx/97/

I'd like to do a very similar chart but it's not working out how I want it to. My current fiddler is this: (see edit below!)

The main functional differece is in the first fiddler, he's using a range, whereas I'm using just actual values (and timestamps).

What's not working for me:

1. The labels are jacked up. If I try to mouse over a point on mine it's way off; it seems to be 'stuck' on the left. If you try to mouse over you should see the same issue.
2. I can't zoom in. On his chart you can't zoom in either, but on another chart I was messing around with, it seems like all I needed to do to add zooming was put in:

   ```
   chart: {
   zoomType: 'x'
   },
   ```

   But that doesn't seem to be working here.
3. The points are so big that the bottom part in green looks too 'blobby'. How can I just remove those point markers?

In summary, how can I have this map have just lines with no blobs, with zooming, and labels that follow your mouse?

EDIT: I have a new version, where the labels work and the blobbiness is removed. However the zoom still doesn't work. How can I enable the zoom?
http://jsfiddle.net/qprmjm67/

Comment: In code you have `zoomtype`, where should be `zoomType`, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qprmjm67/3/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there's a much easier way to do this, using zones.

```
stackoverflow makes me put code to put a link. So I'm typing fake code here.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2f1c659L/